# How do you open a file that the user chooses in python

Tags: python-3.x

What I'm looking for is a way for a user running my program to open a file. Here's my code...

```
userInput = int(input("What file would you like open?"))
#open a file of their choosing using their input (userInput)
```

I looked up how to open a file but I don't know how to use the user's input to open that file.
I have a vague idea but it is not working. 
Help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you would use "with open" to open the file:

```
>>> import os
>>> file = input ("Open file? ")
Open file? sample.txt
>>> file
'sample.txt'
>>> 
>>> if os.path.isfile (file):
    with open (file) as f:
        for line in f:
            print (line)
```

1. Ask user to enter the file path
2. Check to see if the file exists - os.path.isfile (file)
3. Open the file using - with open (file) as f:
4. Do something with the file if it exists or doesn't exists